# how to open html files from windows phone app using window.open method

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, window.open

hi please tell me how to open html files from the phonegap project using window.open method  . I tried this

```
var ref = window.open('http://google.co.in', '_blank', 'location=yes',"width=50,height=50");
```

I can open any file from web. but if i want to open html files from my phonegap project then how can i ? suposse i want to open start.html from my project whose path is /www/start.html,then what should i include in url of open method

Comment: did you try just putting in the html filename without the `http://<domaain>` prefix?i.e just `window.open('<htmlfilename>.html'..`

Comment: yes..i tried..its giving error of url.

Comment: how are you loading your first html(index.html) file in the app? Is it stored locally (in the phone) or are you loading it from server?

Comment: i tried using window.open('start.html');again window.open('/www/start.html') but no one is working.

Comment: how does you app load the first page? what is the name of your starting page and where is it located?

Comment: see..index.html is the first page.start.html is one of the file from the same project.both index.html and start.html are located in /www/ folder.

Comment: index.html is loading locally in the app.

Comment: is start.html located in `/www/start.html` folder or is it located in some sub-folder within `/www/<subfolder>/start.html`? What is the exact error that you are getting.?

Comment: start.html is located in/www folder.

Comment: ok. Are you waiting for deviceready event before opening the local file?

Comment: i just tried that method of phonegap.if u know any other method to open html window in small size in mobile browser then let me now.